# Disable file deletion with numeric DEL key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, file-management, keypad

Is it possible to disable or unmap the DEL key in numeric keypad?

**Rationale**: I normally use the arrow keys with the ENTER key of the numeric  for navigating the filesystem (very convenient location of the ENTER key at the corner of keyb) . Sometimes I suddenly click both DEL and ENTER at the same time as they are neighbor (very inconvenient) which results in accidental deletions.

Comment: You might miss it.  I suggest adding the "file-management" tag, because I think the most desirable answer is to only disable the functionality in Windows Explorer (despite the fact that the question isn't currently worded that way, and is just asking how to remove the key's functionality).  However, the key might be nice to work, as intended, in some o ther programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this tools can help you to make that out.

- Advanced Internet Kiosk
- MapKeyboard from download.com

Taken resource from this site:

http://www.softstack.com/faq/advink/disablekey/disable_delete_key.html

http://blog.enrii.com/2007/11/25/disable-a-certain-key-in-your-keyboard/

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to a free alternative:
https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/ thanks